# Licensing a blog post to a company's blog

Tags: payment-terms, writing, licensing

I have a blog post that brings 3.24% of visitors per month. Startup needs content for their starting blog and they want to license that specific post.

**Have you ever done licensed a blog post to someone else?** On which conditions?

Is it worth it to split your traffic with another company for X money? If yes, what would be a fair value?

Comment: I think this might go better on Freelancing SE.

Comment: I didn't know about such SE! I've asked a moderator to move it.

Answer (score 1):

I was approached about it once, but the licensing terms were quite complex and the expected payout very modest. Figuring out the complexities of the arrangement just did not seem worth the money. I think you would need to be looking at a regular licensing arrangement to make this worthwhile. I don't see how it makes sense for a single post.

There are other considerations, though, beside the money. Will licensing the content extend your brand or compromise it. That is ultimately the more important question. In the end, I could not see how it extended my brand in a meaningful way, so I declined.